# How to perform calculations between childreen of an abstract class in Django

Tags: django, abstract-class

I'm using an abstract base class to perform simple calculations in my models as below:

```
class Base(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    width = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=1, validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
    length = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=1, validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Room(Base):

    room_area = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=1, validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.room_area = self.length*self.width
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Hall(Base):

    hall_area = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=1, validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.hall_area = self.length*self.width
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Let's say I need to find `building_area` which is equal to `building_area = room_area + hall_area`. My problem is that `building_area` will be used by other models and children of `Base` (to calculate other variables). I thought that it would be better if I do the calculation of `building_area` in `Base`. I'm new to Python and Django, so not quite sure how to implement this. Can someone suggest a solution or point out to a good example?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Your current instances are either `Room` or `Hall` so I'm not sure what you're trying to calculate in the `Base` model.

Comment: Also it doesn't make sense to define a field on a model that can be calculated from other fields. You're saving unnecessary data in your database and making it likely you'll hit inconsistencies at some stage. And there's basically no difference between your `Hall` and `Room` models.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! This is just a simplified version of a model. The app recieves an input from the user (room and hall lenghts and widths), the app calculates `room_area`, `hall_area` and `building_area`. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: but room and hall are separate tables in your database. How are they related? You haven't defined any relationship between them. So how do you determine which room_area to add to which hall_area and where do you want to save the total area, you haven't defined a model to save it?

Comment: I have edited my quiestion, I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: First, you don't need the fields `hall_area` and `room_area` as they are just multiplication of the other fields. Just add a property `area` to `Base` that returns width * length. Second, something still doesn't make sense. A `Room` can have multiple `Hall`s? And a building only has one hall and one room? Maybe you need a `Building` model that can have a m2m relationship to multiple rooms and halls. Then you calculate its area on that model.

Comment: Yes you are right, one building can have multiple rooms and halls. I was going to implemetn the multi-table inheritance at the beginnig, but after reading several articles about it, especially this one [link](http://charlesleifer.com/blog/django-patterns-model-inheritance/) and trying it on my app, I found it difficult to reference the child class instances.

Comment: I think you're confusing class inheritance and database relationships. Table (class) inheritance allows you to model different objects that share some properties and methods, like "living room", "bathroom" and "kitchen" all being "rooms" (the **classes** or **tables**). Relationships allow you to model how various **instances** relate to each other, like "this particular building" is related to this particular "hall", "bathroom" and "living room" (the **instances** or **rows** in your table).

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to delegate this kind of operations using a function on the subclasses:

I have the following example:

```
from django.db import models

from ecommerce.shipping.models import Shipping


class Sea(Shipping):
    weight = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, default=0)

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self.cost * self.weight


class Ground(Shipping):
    weight = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, default=0)

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self.cost * self.weight


class Air(Shipping):
    weight = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, default=0)

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self.cost * self.weight
```

You can adapt to your own code, but having this kind of subclasses you can handle easily to have your calculations

```
self.sea = Sea(weight=10, cost=2)
```

if we call `sea.value` the result will be `20` Because of the 
`return self.cost * self.weight`

Comment: you're repeating the same code 3 times, why aren't `weight` and the property `value` defined on the parent class `Shipping`?